# How to take input inside a running action in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Suppose I’ve a running action that generates a list of dynamic buttons to the user. Generally, the button inputted from the user is going to NLU. But I want to know which button the user just picked and act accordingly in this running action. For example, If the user chose “Toyota” I want to call another action from this running action. All I want is not to go to NLU and not to check there. I want everything in my running action. Is it possible? If so, can someone provide the way I can approach?

[image: Chatbot UI]

**My action class is given below.**

```
> class ActionVehicleManufacture(Action):
>     def name(self):
>         return "action_vehicle_manufacturer"
> 
>     def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
>             tracker: Tracker,
>             domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
> 
>         r = requests.get('http://mind.zantrik.com/api/A1/GetVehicleManufacturer')
>         response = r.text
>         json_data = json.loads(response)
>         l = []
>         buttons = []
>         for i in json_data["data"]:
>             l.append(i["manufacturerName"])
>         for i in l:
>             buttons.append({"title": i, "payload": i})
> 
>         dispatcher.utter_message(text="Please let me know you car manufacturer name:", buttons=buttons)
>         # I want to apply some condition here according to users inputted button.
>         return []
```

Comment: The action exits as soon as it utters. so, not possible to fetch user input from the exited action/branch. Only way possible is to fetch from NLU and write a story accordingly with whatever payload the button has.

Answer (score 0):

To call an action after a new user message (e.g, selection of a button or free text) you need to include a story in you storied.md. Which action is arbitrary.  For example:

```
## story example
* ask_about_manufacturers
    - action_vehicle_manufacturer
* inform{"manufacturer": "toyota"}
    - action_execute
```

If you have defined *manufacturer* as a slot, the type of the slot influences the stories. If you have seen [Slots Set By Clicking Buttons](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/#slots-set-by-clicking-buttons), to set the slot *manufacturer* you need to do instead of

```
buttons.append({"title": i, "payload": i})
```

the following, where intent is the intent that captures the message "toyota", in the story example above "inform".

```
buttons.append({"title": i, "payload": f"""/{intent}{{"manufacturer": "i"}}""")
```